# Max Height for Wordpress video?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using a Wordpress block to embed a video, and I want to set a maximum height (in pixels) for the video. There doesn't seem to be a UI way of doing this. Using the "edit as HTML" button, I see the following code:

```
<figure class="wp-block-video wp-block-embed is-type-video is-provider-videopress">
   <div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
      https://videopress.com/v/STUFF?preloadContent=metadata
   </div>
</figure>
```

What's the best way to add a `max-height:320px` to this code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to edit this block using Gutenberg?

Looking to this code I can think there is a CSS hierarchy problem, any online example to test CSS property on this?

Probably you need to handcraft a custom CSS to this problem, and set the height as the way you want.

There's a piece of CSS maybe can help you, I found it on a [Gutenberg issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8383) about this problem:

```css
figure.wp-block-embed.is-type-video {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /*16:9*/
}
figure.wp-block-embed.is-type-video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```